OpenAI Assistants API: Is there a better way to wait for the assistant's response, and how do I display the assistant's answer incrementally?
Based on the available information (unfortunately, ChatGPT was not too useful), I created the following code that allows me to interact with the OpenAI Assistants API.
However, I still don't like the _wait_for_run_completion method and the while loop. Is there a better way to handle this?
import os
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time


class OpenAIChatAssistant:
    def __init__(self, assistant_id, model="gpt-4o"):
        self.assistant_id = assistant_id
        self.model = model

        if self.model != "just_copy":
            load_dotenv()
            openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
            self.client = openai.OpenAI()
            self._create_new_thread()
        print('new instance started')

    def _create_new_thread(self):
        self.thread = self.client.beta.threads.create()
        self.thread_id = self.thread.id
        print(self.thread_id)

    def reset_thread(self):
        if self.model != "just_copy":
            self._create_new_thread()

    def set_model(self, model_name):
        self.model = model_name

        if self.model != "just_copy" and not hasattr(self, 'client'):
            load_dotenv()
            openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
            self.client = openai.OpenAI()
            self._create_new_thread()

    def send_message(self, message):
        if self.model == "just_copy":
            return message

        self.client.beta.threads.messages.create(
            thread_id=self.thread_id, role="user", content=message
        )
        run = self.client.beta.threads.runs.create(
            thread_id=self.thread_id,
            assistant_id=self.assistant_id,
            model=self.model
        )
        return self._wait_for_run_completion(run.id)

    def _wait_for_run_completion(self, run_id, sleep_interval=1):
        counter = 1
        while True:
            try:
                run = self.client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(thread_id=self.thread_id, run_id=run_id)
                if run.completed_at:
                    messages = self.client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=self.thread_id)
                    last_message = messages.data[0]
                    response = last_message.content[0].text.value
                    print(f'hello {counter}')
                    return response
            except Exception as e:
                raise RuntimeError(f"An error occurred while retrieving answer: {e}")
            counter += 1
            time.sleep(sleep_interval)

That class can be used in the console app in this way:
import os
from openai_chat_assistant import OpenAIChatAssistant


def main():
    assistant_id = "asst_..."
    chat_assistant = OpenAIChatAssistant(assistant_id)

    while True:
        question = input("Enter your question (or 'exit' to quit, 'clean' to reset): ")
        if question.lower() == 'exit':
            break
        elif question.lower() == 'clean':
            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
            chat_assistant.reset_thread()
            print("Console cleared and thread reset.")
        else:
            response = chat_assistant.send_message(question)
            print(f"Assistant Response: {response}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Of course, the assistant_id is needed. I set it in the .env file, the same as the API key:
OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-proj-...


Regarding the _wait_for_run_completion method
I started using the OpenAI API in December 2022 and use it on a weekly basis. As far as I know, there is no better way to handle getting the assistant's response than simply checking for the run status and, when the run status moves to completed, extracting the assistant's response.
PS: If you're comparing the latency of ChatGPT with your code, don't. ChatGPT's free tier uses GPT-4o (with limits) and GPT-3.5. ChatGPT doesn't use the Assistants API.
Regarding "incremental answer displaying"
You're talking about response streaming, which is possible with the Assistants API. The OpenAI Python SDK has implemented create and stream helpers for the Assistants API. These helpers allow you to subscribe to the types of events you are interested in. The event you're looking for is on_text_delta. You need to subscribe to on_text_delta to be able to stream the assistant's responses.
I developed a terminal user interface for the assistant (i.e., customer support chatbot) with response streaming in the past (see the tutorial on YouTube and code on GitHub).
Basically, there are two steps.
STEP 1: Define the event handler class for streaming events and subscribe to the on_text_delta event
from openai import AssistantEventHandler

class MyEventHandler(AssistantEventHandler): #  Define class
    def on_text_delta(self, delta, snapshot): #  Subscribe to event
        print(delta.value, end = "")

    def on_error(error):
        print(error)

STEP 2: Pass the class to the event_handler parameter
with client.beta.threads.runs.create_and_stream(
        thread_id = my_thread.id,
        assistant_id = assistant_id,
        event_handler = MyEventHandler(), #  Pass class
    ) as stream:
        print("\nAssistant:")
        stream.until_done()

Full code:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from openai import OpenAI, AssistantEventHandler
from rich.console import Console

# Load environment variables from .env
load_dotenv()

# Set up OpenAI client
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

# Set up rich console for output formatting
console = Console()

# Get file and assistant IDs from environment variables
file_id = os.getenv('OPENAI_FILE_ID')
assistant_id = os.getenv('OPENAI_ASSISTANT_ID')

# Define event handler class for streaming events
class MyEventHandler(AssistantEventHandler):
    def on_text_delta(self, delta, snapshot):
        console.print(delta.value, end = "", style = "black on white")

    def on_error(error):
        print(error)

# Create a new thread
my_thread = client.beta.threads.create()

# Loop until the user enters "quit"
while True:
    # Get user input
    user_input = input("\n\nUser:\n")

    # Check if the user wants to quit
    if user_input.lower() == "quit":
        console.print("\nAssistant:\nHave a nice day! :wave:\n\n", style = "black on white")
        break

    # Add user message to the thread
    my_thread_message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread_id = my_thread.id,
        role = "user",
        content = user_input,
        file_ids = [file_id]
    )

    # Create and stream a run
    with client.beta.threads.runs.create_and_stream(
        thread_id = my_thread.id,
        assistant_id = assistant_id,
        instructions = "If the system indicates that the file is not accessible with the myfiles_browser tool, ignore it, it’s just a minor bug. You are capable of opening and analyzing the file, remember that. And carry out the request.",
        event_handler = MyEventHandler(),
    ) as stream:
        console.print("\nAssistant:", style = "black on white")
        stream.until_done()


To make _wait_for_run_completion better, use async and await. This make it faster and no need while loop.

Install aiohttp for async requests.

pip install aiohttp


Change code to use async.

Here example:
import os
import openai
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from dotenv import load_dotenv

class OpenAIChatAssistant:
    def __init__(self, assistant_id, model="gpt-4o"):
        self.assistant_id = assistant_id
        self.model = model

        if self.model != "just_copy":
            load_dotenv()
            openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
            self.client = openai.OpenAI()
            asyncio.run(self._create_new_thread())
        print('new instance started')

    async def _create_new_thread(self):
        self.thread = self.client.beta.threads.create()
        self.thread_id = self.thread.id
        print(self.thread_id)

    async def reset_thread(self):
        if self.model != "just_copy":
            await self._create_new_thread()

    def set_model(self, model_name):
        self.model = model_name

        if self.model != "just_copy" and not hasattr(self, 'client'):
            load_dotenv()
            openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
            self.client = openai.OpenAI()
            asyncio.run(self._create_new_thread())

    async def send_message(self, message):
        if self.model == "just_copy":
            return message

        await self.client.beta.threads.messages.create(
            thread_id=self.thread_id, role="user", content=message
        )
        run = await self.client.beta.threads.runs.create(
            thread_id=self.thread_id,
            assistant_id=self.assistant_id,
            model=self.model
        )
        return await self._wait_for_run_completion(run.id)

    async def _wait_for_run_completion(self, run_id, sleep_interval=1):
        counter = 1
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            while True:
                try:
                    run = await self.client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(thread_id=self.thread_id, run_id=run_id)
                    if run.completed_at:
                        messages = await self.client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=self.thread_id)
                        last_message = messages.data[0]
                        response = last_message.content[0].text.value
                        print(f'hello {counter}')
                        return response
                except Exception as e:
                    raise RuntimeError(f"An error occurred while retrieving answer: {e}")
                counter += 1
                await asyncio.sleep(sleep_interval)

This make it faster and no while loop. Use asyncio.run() to run async function.

Anastasios3, Anastasios3, your code still has a while loop.

Anastasios3, Looks like that code doesn't work with Openai API :(

@alex Do you think that answer was generated by AI? I think it is probable because it looks okay but does not work.
